# haproxy SSL termination not working for login-page to nginx backend

Tags: nginx, ssl, haproxy

I have nginx pods running inside K8 on port:18080 exposed on nodePort:32070

Next I have an HAPROXY sitting between nginx and public network. I want to configure SSL termination at haproxy level

Below are configs

```
frontend www-http
   bind HAPROXY_IP:80
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
   default_backend www-backend


frontend www-https
   bind HAPROXY_IP:443 ssl crt /var/ssl/server.pem
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
   default_backend www-backend


backend www-backend
   redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
   server www-1 K8_NODE_IP:32070 check
```

The initial page loading is fine, where the login page is displayed. However, when the user tries to log in by providing their username and password, it doesn't redirect to nginx, and there are no entries logged in the haproxy logs.

What did I miss?

Comment: *"but when user tries to login by providing user/pass, it is not redirected to nginx, infact even no entry is logged in haproxy logs"* - where the login data are sent is specified in the login page and has nothing to do with haproxy or nginx setup. You are looking at the wrong place. Check instead what your browser is doing using its developer tools and check the contents of your login page.